# Can redis client work without a redis datastore installed?

Tags: node.js, typescript, redis

In my node web server, I am using a the npm module redis.

when I run my code...

```
const client = redis.createClient();
client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.hmset(["key", "test keys 1", "test val 1", "test keys 2", "test val 2"], function (err, res) {});
```

I get an error:

```
Error Error: Redis connection to 127.0.0.1:6379 failed - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6379
```

I don't have a redis database installed. Do I need that?
If not, anything I have missed in my code?

Comment: Redis is an in-memory datastore, but it's not in-memory in your application process. It requires that your application (here, a node web server) use the redis client to connect over the network to a redis server instance. So, yes, you need a redis database installed to use the redis client.

Comment: is the same case for memcache?

Comment: yes, same for memcache. The intention of these databases is that the front-end web application (your node.js app) can be stateless. Multiple instances of your front-end can connect to the same redis/memcache instance, keeping everything in sync. If you're concerned about performance using the network - don't be! By keeping everything in memory and using smart network protocols, using a redis instance "near" your web front end is wicked fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to install Redis and ensure the server is running. This is a [link](https://redis.io/download) to the official page for downloading the redis.

In your application code, you need to ensure you are connecting to Redis server with the right port and host address. By default, Redis server should be running on `127.0.0.1:6379` and that is where `redis.createClient` would try to connect to by default. If your Redis server is running on another port or host, then you need to specify those details when connecting e.g:

```
redis.createClient({
  host: '<the host where redis is running>',
  port: '<the port where redis is running>'
});
```

You can check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis#rediscreateclient) for more info on the options you can provide when connecting to Redis server with `redis.createClient`.

Comment: to use an in-memory cache, why do I need a full blown database installed. If I need a database installed, so how is it in-memory?

Comment: Pardon my language, it is not a database per-say. What you are installing essentially includes a server that exposes the in-memory db you described along with some other programs required to run Redis. I would update the post to remove the database text.